# Rstudio - Importing Audio Files

Tags: r, audio, soundwaves

I am a beginner in RStudio, and I am planning to use it to analyze audio. I have downloaded wavelets and tuneR packages and have created sine waves and analyzed them. However, I can't seem to get RStudio to read wave files stored on my computer. I have tried readWave, but am continually getting an error:

> file does not exist

How do I get this wave file into RStudio to be analyzed?

Thank you so much for any help you can offer!

Comment: please provide your code, otherwise it is just guessing for us, what is wrong

Comment: > library(tuneR)

> readWave(kupdB.wav, from=1, to=Inf, units=c("samples"), header=FALSE, toWaveMC=NULL)
Error in readWave(kupdB.wav, from = 1, to = Inf, units = c("samples"),  : 
  object 'kupdB.wav' not found
> 1kup<-("kupdB.wav")
Error: unexpected symbol in "1kup"
> kup<-("kupdB.wav")
> readWave(kup, from=1, to=Inf, units=c("samples"), header=FALSE, toWaveMC=NULL)
Error in readWave(kup, from = 1, to = Inf, units = c("samples"), header = FALSE,  : 
  File 'kupdB.wav' does not exist.

Comment: It looks like your working directory is set different in Rstudio than in plain R. The filepath is wrong. You can try to use the full path to the file.

Comment: Thank you! I'm using a file on the Desktop. I tried entering the file path but am getting errors. I tried changing multiple small things and am learning as I go along, but I still must be doing something wrong. Does it have to do with changing the working directory? I'm very new to all of this!

Comment: Here's an example of the code I ran with the file path: 
> readWave(Users//sephr\\Desktop\\R Files\\kupdB.wav, from=1, to=Inf, units=c("samples"), header=FALSE, toWaveMC=NULL)
Error: unexpected '/' in "readWave(Users//"

Comment: One more example, in case it helps: > readWave(C:\\Users/sephr\\Desktop\\R Files\\kupdB.wav, from=1, to=Inf, units=c("samples"), header=FALSE, toWaveMC=NULL)
Error: unexpected input in "readWave(C:\"
> readWave(C:\\Users//sephr\\Desktop\\R Files\\kupdB.wav, from=1, to=Inf, units=c("samples"), header=FALSE, toWaveMC=NULL)
Error: unexpected input in "readWave(C:\"
> readWave( "C:\\Users/sephr\\Desktop\\R Files\\kupdB.wav", from=1, to=Inf, units=c("samples"), header=FALSE, toWaveMC=NULL)
Error in readWave("C:\\Users/sephr\\Desktop\\R Files\\kupdB.wav", from = 1,  : 
  No data chunk found

Comment: Did you created a projekt in Rstudio? If not. create a folder on your Desktop. use create projekt -> existing directory. copy your script and your wav file into the folder. Your working directory should be find then.

Comment: Thank you so much, Linus! This helped! I am able to get my file into my session now. Unfortunately, it is now being recognized as a function rather than a Wave class. Any tips on this? > kupdB.wav<-readWave
> ?tuneR
> play(kupdB.wav)
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘play’ for signature ‘"function"’
> Wobjm11s<-extractWave(kupdB.wav)
Error in extractWave(kupdB.wav) : 
  'object' needs to be of class 'Wave' or 'WaveMC'
> ?Wave
> class(kupdB.wav)
[1] "function"

Comment: kupdB.wav<-readWave('you_file') i do not know the function but you normally need to provide file name to the function.